# remove .php permanently from url

Tags: php, apache, server

I want to remove .php extension from my url,
so I edited `.htaccess` to add this code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

And the code works fine but only when I intentionally remove .php from the URL 
and I want it to be an automatic process so is it possible?

Comment: What do you want to happen exactly if user heads to `http://example.com/foo.php`? An external redirection? A 404 status code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked for me:

```
# To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: 'forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php' that's not what he asked.

Comment: @Jitrenka it will forward the request internaly.

Comment: Worked for me too, thank you!

Comment: @Nuha If it helped you. Please upvote & accept the answer for others.

Answer (score -1):

Are you redirecting to '*.php' in your code? It will of course, append the .php. Remove it and it won't add the extension.

Comment: Thank you! it worked when I did this and added the code from Rana Ghosh